# Putty error trying to Proxy SSH thru SOCK5 proxy: Proxy returned Unexpected Version - any help?

Tags: ssh, putty, socks-proxy

I get an error trying to connect to a server thru SSH via a SOCK5 proxy with Putty.

The error is: Proxy returned Unexpected Version

Any clue what this error is, or how to troubleshoot?   the Proxy connection works via FileZilla and Mozilla.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure your proxy is a SOCKS-5 proxy.  The error message you are getting is telling you that Putty is expecting the proxy version to be 5 and that the proxy is returning an incorrect version (not 5).

If you can interpret a bit of code you can see exactly what's happening by looking at the [Putty proxy code](http://svn.tartarus.org/sgt/putty/proxy.c?view=markup) and a quick look at the [SOCKS protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Socks5#SOCKS_5_protocol).